# Convert JSON to file system in firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, filesystems, google-cloud-functions

I have this json and i want to convert it to file system which i will zip later and convert it to base64 and upload it to firebase storage. I want to get this done in a firebase cloud function.

```
"-L1ssSkLLlOLM7zpXz6M" : {
    "scenes" : [ {
      "scene" : {
        "slides" : [ {
          "image" : "This is base64"
        }, {
          "image" : "This is base64"
        }, {
          "image" : "This is base64"
        }, {
          "image" : "This is base64"
        } ]
      },
      "text" : "test 3"
    }, {
      "scene" : {
        "slides" : [ {
          "image" : "This is base64"
        }, {
          "image" : "This is base64"
        }, {
          "image" : "This is base64"
        }, {
          "image" : "This is base64"
        }, {
          "image" : "This is base64"
        } ]
      },
      "text" : "test 4"
    } ],
    "title" : "Hello"
  }
```

Is it possible to do so ?

Here is what i want the folder to look like 
https://ufile.io/mhrhz

Comment: Storing and zipping the JSON sounds possible. Where are you stuck?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thats possible but i first need to create a folder with subfolders and then zip that folder. I don't know how to convert JSON to folder.

Comment: That's again a few steps: parsing the JSON, finding/creating a folder on the temp/RAM disk of your Cloud Functions environment. If you show what you've already tried and where you are stuck, it is much more likely that we can help effectively.